# How to set building in sequence like COC game using tiles map in cocos2d-x V3.9?

Tags: tilemap, cocos2d

i am developing game in cocos2d-x V3.9. i want to create base like COC game. set all buildings in sequence and it can't be overlap with each others. i want also make boundary for develop city view. user can't develop city out of boundary. please anyone help me or give demo link for same.

Comment: So you are asking for some game code that does what you are asking? At least try to make it yourself. Also COC... Is that supposed to mean Clash of Clans? Always be as specific as possible when asking for help. Before thinking on how to control the buildings do you already have code that displays a blank map, handles creation of the sprites and maintains a basic game state? That is why we cannot provide you code for this, too complex to answer on the site.

Comment: No, i just asking for some hint. i already create basic city view using .tmx file  that are created in *Tiled Map Editor*. but i was stuck at how to manage building in sequence? and also change in tiles map file dynamically. i follow below link for create city view.  can you help me in this scenario?  [https://www.raywenderlich.com/39113/cocos2d-x-tile-map-tutorial-part-1]

Answer (score 0):

What you want has more to do with how to implement basic isometric view systems. If I'm understanding correctly that COC stands for Clash of Clans, without having played the game I think it's a somewhat isometric view system.

Isometric could and probably should be thought of more as a 3D projection than a 2D projection, meaning that there is a certain "depth" to the map. This would mean that simple X and Y coordinates won't do for rendering order. It also needs a Z to indicate distance from a certain point. I don't believe Tiled has built-in support to manually indicate a Z coordinate, but with some relatively simple math you should be able to calculate the distance of a building from another point on the map.

The farther away the objects are from the front of the map (front being closest to the camera), the *earlier* they should be drawn. This has a name, it's called the [Painter's Algorithm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm)

[Here's a nice tutorial to get you started with depth-sorting.](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-cheap-n-easy-isometric-levels--gamedev-6282)

Every time you add another building, you should put it in its appropriate place in the children list, to make sure it's rendered before the buildings in front of it, and after buildings behind it.

[Another very interesting tutorial.](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-isometric-worlds-a-primer-for-game-developers--gamedev-6511)

Comment: Clash of Clans is built on Supercell's own game engine which they use for all 4 of their games. It is a 2d game engine, so the entire game is actually 2d (top down), its just that the graphics make it looks 3d.

Comment: @Gloin Yes. But I'm saying to have the sprites render correctly you should think of the plane like it exists in 3D space, even though it's obviously only 2 dimensions. Otherwise buildings and sprites in general will appear in front of each other regardless of where their representation says it will. I.E. If a building is added to a scene graph later on, it'll be rendered later (usually). In an isometric perspective this could mean the building appears in front of other sprites even though its 3D representation/its location could be behind them.